# How to protect a post request payload to the server?

Tags: https, httprequest, html-post

When I enter username, password and hit the login button, then a POST request goes to the server.

Does the password go in plain text format in the header? And so is https the only solution to encrypt the communication so an attacker cannot view it?

Comment: Q: Does the password go in plain text format in the header? A: Yes.  Q: is https the only solution?  A: No.

Comment: What else is possible.?